# Columns in Excel VBA - Invalid matrix index for property

Tags: vba, excel

I'm getting an error when I try to write two columns to cell A1.
What is wrong and how do I solve it?

```
Private Sub ComboBox1_DropButtonClick()

Sheet1.Range("A1").Value = Me.ComboBox1.Column(0) & " " & 

Me.ComboBox1.Column(1)

End Sub
```

Error message

> The Column property can not be retrieved. Invalid matrix index for property.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well I think column counting starts with `1` not `0`.

So you get the value of the combobox with `Me.ComboBox1.Value` and the column (right next to the value) with `Me.ComboBox1.Column(1)`.

```
Private Sub ComboBox1_Click()
    Sheet1.Range("A1").Value = Me.ComboBox1.Value & " " & Me.ComboBox1.Column(1)
End Sub
```

See here for a tutorial on [Multicolumn Combo Box](http://%20http://www.excel-easy.com/vba/examples/multicolumn-combo-box.html).

Comment: Same error unfortunately. I have loaded my combobox with 4 columns and in cell A1 I want to write data that exists in both columns 0 and 1. I have understood that the first column is 0? I use LinkedCell in object properties to save my BoundColumn  3 in cell A2.

Comment: Oh, of course you need to use the `ComboBox1_Click()` instead of the `ComboBox1_DropButtonClick()`. And there is no `column(0)` it starts with `column(1)` what you meant to be column `0` is actually the value `ComboBox1.Value`